# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter of 'aname'

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm a beginner developer and most of the time i get a error its hard to find out what is wrong with my code.
The error im getting:

> CS7036 C# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter of 'aname' of 'InventoryManager.addItem(string,int,double)'

I am not sure if this is related to the actually method,object or calling the method.

Any Help would be very helpfull

**Object**

```
class Item
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public static int ID = 0; 
    private double apriceEach;

    public string name { get; set; }
    public int quantityInStock { get; set; }
    public double priceEach { get; set; }

    public Item(int aid, string aname, int aquantityInStock, double apriceEach) 
    {
        this.id = aid;
        this.name = aname;
        this.quantityInStock = aquantityInStock;
        this.priceEach = apriceEach;

    }

    public Item(string aname, int aid, double apriceEach) : this(aname, aid)
    {
        this.apriceEach = apriceEach;
    }

    public int myID
    {

        get { return id;}
    }

    public Item(string aname, int aid)
    {
        name = aname;
        aid++;
        this.id = ID;
    }
}
```

**Methods**

```
class InventoryManager
{
    List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

    internal void addItem( string aname, int aquantityInStock, double apriceEach)
    {
        Item addingItem = new Item(aname, aquantityInStock, apriceEach);
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Item Name: ");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        name = aname;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Item Qunatity: ");
        var quantity = Console.ReadLine();
        int quantityInStock = Convert.ToInt32(quantity);
        quantityInStock = aquantityInStock;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Price per Each Item: ");
        var price = Console.ReadLine();
        double priceEach = Convert.ToDouble(price);
        priceEach = apriceEach;
        items.Add((new Item(aname, aquantityInStock, apriceEach)));
        throw new NotImplementedException();

    }

    public  void removeItem(int aid)
    {
        Item result = null;
        foreach (var a in items)
        {
            if (a.id == aid)
            {
                result = a;
            }


        }
        items.Remove(result);
        Console.WriteLine("Item Taken");

    } 
    public int findItem(int x)
    {
        return x;
    }
    public int getAllitems(int x)
    {
        return x;
    }
}
```

**UI**

```
public void Run()
    {

        var run = true;

        while(run)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("1: Add stock");
            Console.WriteLine("2: Remove Stock");
            Console.WriteLine("3: Inventory Report");
            Console.WriteLine("4: Financial Report");
            Console.WriteLine("5: Display Transactions");
            Console.WriteLine("6: Personal Usage");

            var runtInput = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (runtInput)
            {
                case "1":
                    instance.addItem();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `internal void addItem( string aname, int aquantityInStock, double apriceEach)` vs `instance.addItem();` - Can you spot a difference between the method signature, and the code you're using to call it? Hint: none of these parameters are optional.

Comment: Your `addItem` method is defined as `internal void addItem( string aname, int aquantityInStock, double apriceEach)` it means that it require 3 parameters.
`aname` - item name.
`aquantityInStock` - quantity
and `apriceEach` - price per item.
But in your code you trying to call your method without these parameters:
`instance.addItem();`. You should update this line by adding the required parameters. E.g. you can request item name, quantity, and price per item from the user and use provided values to call this method.

Comment: im not sure which parameter is optional to run it. would i need to pass these through to instance.addItem(); ?

Comment: @Vyacheslav Benedichuk im not sure how would i be able to do that. with having the paramaters in instance.addItem(); it still throws me syntax errors.